# How can I convert JSON-encoded data that contains Unicode surrogate pairs to string?

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.5, emoji

so I am trying to take this data that uses unicode indicators and make it print with emojis. It is currently in a txt. file but I will write to an excel file later. So anyways I am getting an error I am not sure what to do with. This is the text I am reading:

```
"Thanks @UglyGod \ud83d\ude4f https:\\/\\/t.co\\/8zVVNtv1o6\"
"RT @Rosssen: Multiculti beatdown \ud83d\ude4f https:\\/\\/t.co\\/fhwVkjhFFC\"
```

And here is my code:

```
sampleFile= open('tweets.txt', 'r').read()
splitFile=sampleFile.split('\n')
for line in sampleFile:
    x=line.encode('utf-8')
    print(x.decode('unicode-escape'))
```

This is the error Message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode byte 0x5c in position 0: \ at end of string
```

Any ideas?
This is how the data was originally generated.

```
class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        # Check for a field unique to tweets (if missing, return immediately)
        if "in_reply_to_status_id" not in data:
            return
        with open("see_no_evil_monkey.csv", 'a') as saveFile:
            try:
                saveFile.write(json.dumps(data) + "\n")
            except (BaseException, e):
                print ("failed on data", str(e))
                time.sleep(5)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)
```

Comment: How was `tweets.txt` generated?

Comment: You are trying to decode a `bytes` object with 'unicode-escape' that was previously encoded with 'utf8', 'unicode-escape' cannot read strings encoded with 'utf8'.

I believe the simplest solution to your problem would be to pass the correct encoding to the `open` function when reading from the file.

Comment: So this is the code that was used to generate the original data from twitter:

Comment: Hey, I added how the file information was generated

Answer (score 4):

> This is how the data was originally generated... `saveFile.write(json.dumps(data) + "\n")`

You should use `json.loads()` instead of `.decode('unicode-escape')` to read JSON text:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

with open('tweets.txt', encoding='ascii') as file:
    for line in file:
        text = json.loads(line)
        print(text)
```

Comment: OK, so your method is working for me now when I just write the emoji to a text file. The full contents are `"\ud83d\ude4f"` plus a newline. I guess `json` is handling the surrogate pairs under the hood. Question is, if I have a surrogate pair in a regular string (Py3 unicode string) represented as `"\ud83d\ude4f"` like the OP, how do I process that to print the emoji? Everything I tried gave me errors about surrogate pairs.

Comment: @MattDMo OP uses `json.dumps()` and therefore there are no non-ASCII characters in the file at all (do you see `encoding="ascii"` in my answer). The case you are describing has nothing to do with parsing the result of `json.dumps()` as OP needs. If you have a different question then ask it as a separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: OK, I'll ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Your emoji  is represented as a [surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates), see also [here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%F0%9F%99%8F) for info about this particular glyph. Python cannot decode surrogates, so you'll need to look at exactly how your `tweets.txt` file was generated, and try encoding the original tweets, along with the emoji, as UTF-8. This will make reading and processing the text file much easier.

Comment: Python can decode surrogates just fine. It is how JSON can represent non-BMP characters.