# Python unicode string - position

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, position, substring

I stuck with getting the position inside a String.
I read the content of a file

```
with io.open(testfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f

\u2705 Offizielle Kan\u00e4le \ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddea  \ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddf9 \ud83c\udde8\ud83c\udded\n@GET_THIS_STING
```

What do I have to do - that "\u2705" is counted as 1 letter?
Then Position 36 would be the start of @GET_THIS_STING

**--== EDIT ==--**
I can now better show whats the problem:

```
import json
from io import open

line = '{"message":{"message_id":3052,"text":"\u2705 Offizielle Kan\u00e4le \ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddea  \ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddf9 \ud83c\udde8\ud83c\udded\\n@GET_THIS_STING\\n123456789","entities":[{"offset":36,"length":26,"type":"mention"}]}}'
myjson = json.loads(line)
text = myjson.get("message", {}).get("text", None)
print(str(text).encode('utf-8', 'replace').decode())
print("string length: " + str(len(text)))
print(text[36:36+15])

print("-------------")

with open("/home/pi/telegram/phpLogs/test.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors="surrogateescape") as f:
    for line in f:
        myjson = json.loads(line)

        text = myjson.get("message", {}).get("text", None)
        print(text)
        print("string length: " + str(len(text)))
        print(text[36:36+15])
```

**RESULT:**

```
✅ Offizielle Kanäle ????  ???? ????
@GET_THIS_STING
123456789
string length: 61
@GET_THIS_STING
-------------
✅ Offizielle Kanäle    
@GET_THIS_STING123456789
string length: 54
HIS_STING123456
```

So when I have the string inside my code (UTF-8) as a variable (String), everything works fine.
But when I create a file with content and read it

```
"{"message":{"message_id":3052,"text":"\u2705 Offizielle Kan\u00e4le \ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddea  \ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddf9 \ud83c\udde8\ud83c\udded\\n@GET_THIS_STING\\n123456789","entities":[{"offset":36,"length":26,"type":"mention"}]}}"
```

I always receive a "wrong" result :(
So reading a file is my problem, because the strings are not the same afterwards - even the length is different!

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: python version 3.6 on a Raspberry with Raspbian
And yes - the file contains the string with \u

Answer (score 0):

If your file `text.txt` literally contains,

```
\u2705 Offizielle Kan\u00e4le \ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddea  \ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddf9 \ud83c\udde8\ud83c\udded\n@GET_THIS_STING
```

Try:

```py
with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    str = f.read()
    normal_str = ''
    i, n = 0, 0
    while i < len(str):
        if str[i: i + 2] == '\\u':
            i += 6
            normal_str += 'x'
        elif str[i: i + 2] == '\\n':
            i += 2
            normal_str += 'x'
        else:
            normal_str += str[i]
            i += 1
        n += 1
    print(normal_str)
    print(normal_str[36:36 + 15])
```

And, this outputs:

```
x Offizielle Kanxle xxxx  xxxx xxxxx@GET_THIS_STING

@GET_THIS_STING
```

With a file `text.txt` that looks something like this,

```
✅ Offizielle Kanäle    
@GET_THIS_STING
```

We can do,

```py
with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    str = f.read()
    index = str.find('@')
    print('char @ is at index: {}'.format(index))
    print(str[index:])
```

It outputs,

```
char @ is at index: 30
@GET_THIS_STING
```

Comment: the problem is, that I can not search for a possition - I have the position - so I have to use mystring[36:36+15]
The string is a result I stored from the Telegram API - and there you have a list of Entities with "offset", "lenght" to know the position inside the text

Comment: If you have the string why can you not search? What exactly are the contents of your file you are reading?

Comment: I added into the Main Post 1:1 an example.
Still my problem is, when reading the String from a file, I get a different result than procedding the string in the code as variable directly.

So pritty sure an encoding issue.

Comment: Your post is not very easy to read. If you want help, then get a sample string and perform the function on it by hand and show the desired output. If I understand your problem, then the last update to my answer should solve it. It does not matter how your string is encoded as long as you don't need the data that is not encoded correctly. You want the encoding to be consistent even if wrong so you can filter out the data you really care for.

Answer (score 0):

If this string represents `✅ Offizielle Kanäle`     as suggested by @scribe's answer, then I think you run into the problem mentioned here: [Converting to Emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106422/converting-to-emoji)

Therefore I suggest replacing

```
with io.open(testfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read() # you didn't show it but probably that's what you have done
```

with

```
with open(testfile, 'r', encoding='ascii') as f:
    text = json.load(f)
```

or, if the file is "JSON lines" rather than single JSON:

```
with open(testfile, 'r', encoding='ascii') as f:
    for line in f:
        text = json.loads(line)
```

and then `text` will be a proper Unicode string, so `text[36:]` should get you what you asked for.

Comment: very close to the solution I need - it seems that the \n is now not counted.
But this also should be counted - in my Example I would get with your code "GET_THIS_STING" without the "@" which is missing because of the line break.

This problem shifts the results the more \n I have.

For every \n the result is cut of the amount of it

Comment: edit: emojies seem to make Problems -- in sum my result gets missing 6 letters - so its shifted to 6 -- "IS_STING" - the \n is NOT the issue, it seems to be counted -- so the 3 flags are not counted right

Comment: This, in turn, seems to be a problem with surrogate characters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147259/how-to-work-with-surrogate-pairs-in-python so try adding this: `text = text.encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')`

Comment: I get with myjson = myjson.encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16') --- AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: \ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddea should be counted as 4, but is counted as 2 because the Flag is interpreted as "DE"

Comment: No no no, you need to do it on a string, not a dict. Check where in `myjson` your string is… probably as a value for some key.