# JSON.loads encoding issues - File vs. String

Tags: python, json, encoding, utf-8, telegram

I get 2 different results when trying to json.load a string

- once I load it from a String in my .py code file with is utf8
- than I load the string I put to a file with utf8 encoding

But, the length of the "text" part is different and so I can not parse a part of the string given in the entities.

What do I have to do, that also from File, I can get the same length to get the given substring at position 36 - with length 14?

```
import json
from io import open

line = '{"message":{"message_id":3052,"text":"\u2705 Offizielle Kan\u00e4le \ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddea  \ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddf9 \ud83c\udde8\ud83c\udded\\n@GET_THIS_USER\\n123456789","entities":[{"offset":36,"length":14,"type":"mention"}]}}'
myjson = json.loads(line)
text = myjson.get("message", {}).get("text", None)
print(str(text).encode('utf-8', 'replace').decode())
print("string length: " + str(len(text)))
print("Entity String = " + text[36:36+14])

print("-------------")

with open("/home/pi/telegram/phpLogs/test3.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors="surrogateescape") as f:
    for line in f:
        myjson = json.loads(line)

        text = myjson.get("message", {}).get("text", None)
        print(text)
        print("string length: " + str(len(text)))
        print("Entity String = " + text[36:36+14])
```

Line I put to the file

```
{"message":{"message_id":3052,"text":"\u2705 Offizielle Kan\u00e4le \ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddea  \ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddf9 \ud83c\udde8\ud83c\udded\n@GET_THIS_USER\n123456789","entities":[{"offset":36,"length":14,"type":"mention"}]}}
```

Result I get when running with python 3.6

```
✅ Offizielle Kanäle ????  ???? ????
@GET_THIS_USER
123456789
string length: 60
Entity String = @GET_THIS_USER
-------------
✅ Offizielle Kanäle    
@GET_THIS_USER
123456789
string length: 54
Entity String = HIS_USER
12345
```

So in the file the line is 6 characters shorter and the position is shifted that "@GET_T" is cut :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python unicode string - position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61571276/python-unicode-string-position)

Answer (score 0):

1. `\u....` escape sequences in Python string literals are interpreted:

   ```
   >>> print('\u2705 Offizielle Kan\u00e4le')
   ✅ Offizielle Kanäle
   ```

   Meaning, your JSON string literal does *not* contain "backslash u ....", but already interpreted characters. To get the same effect as reading from a text file, where those character sequences *aren't* implicitly interpreted, you'd need to double all backslashes, or prefix your string literal with `r`:

   ```
   line = r'{"message" ...}'
   ```

   Because you don't want *Python* to interpret those escape sequences, but the JSON parser…
2. Those flag emoji are above the BMP in the Unicode table. Python can encode that directly:

   ```
   >>> '\U0001f1e9\U0001f1ea'  # U+1F1E9 U+1F1EA
   ''
   ```

   ECMAScript operates on UTF-16 encoding and can *not* directly represent code points above U+FFFF, and it needs to use surrogate pairs; hence `U+1F1E9 U+1F1EA` encodes to `\ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddea` in UTF-16/ECMAScript/JSON. Those code points are invalid/non-sensical in Python string literals though because they're not interpreted as UTF-16 surrogates.
3. This is pretty superfluous:

   ```
   print(str(text).encode('utf-8', 'replace').decode())
   ```

   Just `print(text)`. This will of course give this error message:

   ```
   UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 58-61: surrogates not allowed
   ```

   Which is a hint for the symptom described in point 2 above, which is a consequence of point 1. Your attempted workaround just hides that issue by discarding those surrogates and replacing them with `?`.

Comment: But version 1 from string inside the code like I posted works. ----> the issue comes when loading the content from the file! (version 2) ----> for me it is not important how the text line or string is printed - the goal would be that as RESULT I also get "Entity String = @GET_THIS_USER" when reading from file with pos 36 + 14 length

Comment: your "r" - version makes the results the same - thats true - but breaks the working verion from the string - if you can give me a way to read from file like it is in the string - it would be solved ;)

Comment: No, the version reading from the file is the correct version! Your string literal version is the broken one.

Comment: But what should I do, if my file looks like it is and the Entities are guiding me the position inside the Text to find the right postion of "mentioned"??? Even if it would be wrong - I am searching for a way to find the correct position inside the text --- if it would be neccessary to rewrite the file - I also would be fine - but the Entitiy position is fixed - so I need to find a way reading the file, like I was reading the string in my Example.

Comment: So, you're given that JSON and a string position calculated based on the UTF-16 character count and you can't change that? And that's immovable? Oh boy… You'd probably have to convert the string to UTF-16 and do your offset calculations based on that, but I won't be figuring this out for you right now. I'd advise you to open a new question which very specifically asked about exactly _that_.